# How do I create an automated recurring Google email using Apps Script to run five days a week?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to set up a recurring automated email through Gmail. I was able to successfully create a script where it ran daily, however, I'd only like it to run 5 days a week (Sunday-Thursday) at a specific time (5 pm). When I updated the script to include these triggers, the emails do not send. Does anyone have advice? Thanks in advance!

Here's my Apps Script code:

```
Function sendEmails() {
 
  var emailAddress = 'email@email.com';
  var subject = 'Reminder: reminder';
  var message = 'Content of message';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: message,
  });
  }
  function createTriggers() {
   var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY, ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.SUNDAY];
   for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("send emails")
               .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
               .atHour(17).create();
   }
}
```

Comment: When I saw your script, the function name you want to run is `sendEmails`. But in your script for installing trigger, `send emails` is used. About this, how about modifying from `send emails` to `sendEmails`? By the way, I think that `Function` of `Function sendEmails() {` is `function`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function testfunc(e) {
  if(~[1,2,3,4,7].indexOf(e.day-of-week) ) {
    sendEmails()
  }
}

function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'testFunc').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('testfunc').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(17).create();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is creating multiple event-driven triggers instead of adding this in the code.

Sample code below is what worked for me:

```
function sendRecurringEmail() {

  var recipient = "recipient@example.com";

  var subject = "Recurring Email Subject";

  var body = "This is the body of the recurring email.";

  // Send the email

  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```